# Hall theorem with non-saturating matching

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, matching-theory

[Hall's marriage theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem#Graph_theoretic_formulation) states that given a bipartite graph $G=(X+Y,E)$, if there is no $X$-saturating matching, there there exists $W\subseteq X$ such that $|W|>|N_G(W)|$.

Is the following generalized version true: if there is no matching that covers at least $|X|-k$ vertices of $X$, then there exists $W\subseteq X$ such that $|W|>|N_G(W)|+k$? I believe it is true by a similar proof as Hall's theorem, but it is not mentioned in the Wikipedia page. Is there a reference about this?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is true, it is sometimes called "generalized Hall theorem". It may be reduced to $k=0$ case by the [following trick](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/271608/17-camels-trick): add $k$ new vertices to $Y$ and join them with all vertices in $X$. New graph satisfies the conditions of Hall theorem, choose an $X$-saturated matching in it and remove the edges which are incident to added vertices.